# Invalid Date output given by momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Applying momentjs on my date string is giving me deprecation warning followed by invalid date

Initial attempt:

`console.log(moment("1546728489000").format('LLLL'));`

warning and console output for above intial attempt:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO 
format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable 
across all browsers and versions.

Invalid date
```

I tried to convert the format of my date by wrapping it with new Date() function. This got rid of deprecation warning but still outputs `invalid date` in the console

modified code:

`console.log(moment(new Date("1546728489000")).format('LLLL'));`

What should i do to avoid `invalid date` getting logged in the console and get the format as per below?

`Tuesday, March 26, 2019 6:02 PM`

Answer (score 3):

you are using string, timestamp needs to be integer

```
moment(1546728489000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the timestamp value from string to integer
Something like this-

```
console.log(moment(1546728489000).format('LLLL'))
```